# Bug in SharePoint 2013 : adding a enterprise wiki page

Tags: publishing-page, sharepoint-server, bug

When I view my site content and go to the pages library ( Enterprise wiki template ) I can add a new Enterprise wiki page from the ribbon ( select new than enterprise wiki page ). It redirect me to a page where I can fill in the title and URL of the new page. After I press create I get redirected to a blank page instead of my newly created page. If i return to the page library I see the page is created but I wonder why I get redirected to that blank page. In the URL it doesn't state about:blank but a long URL like this :

```
http://ins-sp2013/_layouts/15/wpribbon.aspx?
GetFormName=0&WebPartId=g_71168d0d_f668_4421_8b54_9630c957d080&PageComponentId=WebPartWPQ2&L
ist=14422d25-37a2-4c3a-a1bc-38d3a107d8df&View=71168d0d-f668-4421-8b54-
9630c957d080&FileUrl=%2FPages%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx
```

Comment: Did you out anything new about this error? I'm running into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on a Publishing Page Libary.  I set the toolbar to No Toolbar on the AllItems.aspx page.  Removing the toolbar causes the page to stop processing.  Browse to the AllItems.aspx page and edit the page > edit web part > check tool bar type.  Set to Full Toolbar and save.

This should resolve the issue.